# How can I make an svg wave like this one?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I make a svg like this one

[image of wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEpDo.png)

This is what i have so far. i tried using a a generator called haikei to make it but couldn't get it to match.

```
<svg id="visual" viewBox="0 0 960 540" width="960" height="540" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="960" height="540" fill="#002233"></rect><path d="M0 382L22.8 387.5C45.7 393 91.3 404 137 413.2C182.7 422.3 228.3 429.7 274 434.7C319.7 439.7 365.3 442.3 411.2 446.5C457 450.7 503 456.3 548.8 447.5C594.7 438.7 640.3 415.3 686 404.7C731.7 394 777.3 396 823 402.3C868.7 408.7 914.3 419.3 937.2 424.7L960 430L960 541L937.2 541C914.3 541 868.7 541 823 541C777.3 541 731.7 541 686 541C640.3 541 594.7 541 548.8 541C503 541 457 541 411.2 541C365.3 541 319.7 541 274 541C228.3 541 182.7 541 137 541C91.3 541 45.7 541 22.8 541L0 541Z" fill="#0066FF" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path></svg>
```

Comment: You can write the code manually, or you could use something like Figma or Illustrator and just export the SVG.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I took your `.png`, put it into illustrator, traced the image, exported as an SVG, and ran through [SVGO](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/). This was the output:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 612 45.9"><path d="M612 16.14V45.9H0v-30C44.75 4.62 91.71 1.24 137.34 0h18.29c37.23.92 75.86 3.65 113.19 9.37 33.65 5.35 66.93 13.09 100.86 16.64 80.51 9.28 163.14 8.49 242.32-9.87Z" fill="#407dc0"/></svg>
```